# Iterating over only a part of list in Python

Tags: python, iteration

I have a list in python, that consists of both alphabetic and numeric elements, say something like `list = ["a", 1, 2, 3, "b", 4, 5, 6]` and I want to slice it into 2 lists, containing numbers that follow the alphabetic characters, so `list1 = [1, 2, 3]` and `list2 = [4, 5, 6]`. `a` and `b` elements could be in reversed order, but generally, I want to store numeric elements that follow `a` and `b` elements in separate lists. The easiest solution that I came up with was creating a loop with condition:

```
    #Generating a list for numeric elements following "a":
    for e in list[list.index("a")+1:]:
      if not str.isdigit(e):
       break
      else:
       list1.append(e)
```

I'd do it similarly for `list2` and numeric elements after `"b"`.
But could there be more elegant solutions? I'm new to Python, but I've seen beautiful one-liner constructions, could there be something like that  in my case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify the question a bit more, for example by giving a full code example?

Comment: Better now :D but I think the title is still confusing... Do you want to iterate over a list and skip specific elements or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this, maybe?

```
>>> import itertools
>>> import numbers
>>> lst = ["a", 1, 2, 3, "b", 4, 5, 6]
>>> groups = itertools.groupby(lst, key=lambda x: isinstance(x, numbers.Number))
>>> result = [[x for x in group_iter] for is_number, group_iter in groups if is_number]
>>> result
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

And here is a less “sexy” version that outputs a list of tuple pairs `(group_key, group_numbers)`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> import numbers
>>> lst = ["a", 1, 2, 3, "b", 4, 5, 6]
>>> groups = itertools.groupby(lst, key=lambda x: isinstance(x, numbers.Number))
>>> group_key = None
>>> result = []
>>> for is_number, group_iter in groups:
...     if not is_number:
...         for x in group_iter:
...             group_key = x
...     else:
...         result.append((group_key, [x for x in group_iter]))
>>> result
[('a', [1, 2, 3]), ('b', [4, 5, 6])]
```

Note that it is a quick and dirty version which expects the input data to be well-formed.

Comment: like this solution, I was thinking of it myself, but could not get to it, thanks for sharing

Answer (score 3):

Here you have a functional aproach:

```
>>> l = ["a", 1, 2, 3, "b", 4, 5, 6]
>>> dig = [x for (x, y) in enumerate(l) if type(y) is str] + [len(l)]
>>> dig
[0, 4, 8]
>>> slices = zip(map(lambda x:x+1, dig), dig[1:])
>>> slices
[(1, 4), (5, 8)]
>>> lists = map(lambda (i, e): l[i:e], slices)
>>> lists
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

First we get the index of the letters with, notice that we need the size of the list to know the end of it:

```
[x for (x, y) in enumerate(l) if type(y) is str] + [len(l)]
```

Then we get the pair of slices where the lists are:

```
zip(map(lambda x:x+1, dig), dig[1:])
```

Finally, we get each slice from the original list:

```
map(lambda (i, e): l[i:e], slices)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use slices:

```
list = ["a", 1, 2, 3, "b", 4, 5, 6]
lista = list[list.index('a')+1:list.index('b')]
listb = list[list.index('b')+1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (Python 3 only):

```
def chunks(values, idx=0):
    ''' Yield successive integer values delimited by a character. '''

    tmp = []
    for idx, val in enumerate(values[1:], idx):
        if not isinstance(val, int):
            yield from chunks(values[idx + 1:], idx)
            break
        tmp.append(val)
    yield tmp


>>> values = ['a', 1, 2, 3, 'b', 4, 5, 6]
>>> list(chunks(values))
[[4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]]
```